# How to shuffle an array in PHP while still knowing the original index?

Tags: php, arrays, shuffle

How do you shuffle a PHP array while still knowing the original index?

I have a simple array in PHP (e.g. `["a", "b", "c", [5, 10]]`).

The `shuffle()` function allows you to shuffle the elements.

However I still wish know what the original index was. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [shuffle doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) 2nd  example:

```
<?php
    function shuffle_assoc(&$array) {
        $keys = array_keys($array);

        shuffle($keys);

        foreach($keys as $key) {
            $new[$key] = $array[$key];
        }

        $array = $new;

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean shuffle the elements and keep them with their keys, so if you `foreach` over them they come out in a shuffled order? That's possible by reshaping the array into a list of `[key, value]` pairs:

```
$pairs = array_map(null, array_keys($array), array_values($array));
```

So `["a", "b", "c", [5, 10]]` becomes `[[0, "a"], [1, "b"], [2, "c"], [3, [5, 10]]`.

Then, shuffle the pairs:

```
shuffle($pairs);
```

Which might end up something like this (random each time obviously):

```
[[2, "c"], [1, "b"], [3, [5, 10]], [0, "a"]]
```

Finally, re-shape it into a normal array again:

```
$shuffled = array_combine(array_column($pairs, 0), array_column($pairs, 1));
```

End result looks something like this:

```
[2 => "c", 1 => "b", 3 => [5, 10], 0 => "a"]
```

Is that what you want?

This is just one way to do it, though. What Gerard suggested is probably more efficient.

Comment: I don't know if this solution is less efficient than others, but I prefer it over ALL the ones I've seen today. This does not depend on a loop. Thank you @mystery :)

Comment: @DarioFerrer I'm glad you liked it! I've just realised that you might be able to simplify the last step to `$shuffled = array_column($pairs, 1, 0);` though haven't tried it.