# Sort multiple array with same order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Below is example of my array

```
["value"]=>
  array(16) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "4"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "2"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "1"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "3"

 }
  ["id"]=>
  array(16) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "four-id"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "two-id"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "one-id"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "three-id" 
 }
```

Now I am sorrting using  `array_multisort($arr["value"],SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC);` , which results in below output.

```
   ["value"]=>
      array(16) {
        [0]=>
        string(5) "4"
        [1]=>
        string(4) "3"
        [2]=>
        string(4) "2"
        [3]=>
        string(4) "1"

     }
      ["id"]=>
      array(16) {
        [0]=>
        string(4) "four-id"
        [1]=>
        string(4) "two-id"
        [2]=>
        string(4) "one-id"
        [3]=>
        string(4) "three-id" 
     }
```

I want `$arr["id"]` to be sorted based on same sorting order of `$arr["value"]` like below

```
      ["id"]=>
      array(16) {
        [0]=>
        string(4) "four-id"
        [1]=>
        string(4) "three-id"
        [2]=>
        string(4) "two-id"
        [3]=>
        string(4) "one-id" 
     }
```

Comment: You should consider re-structuring the array to use the ID as the key for the values, you could use then a custom sorting function as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842331/how-to-shuffle-an-array-in-php-while-still-knowing-the-original-index

Answer (score 0):

You can use `krsort`

```
$array_1 = Array(4,2,1,3);
$array_2 = Array('four-id','two-id','one-id','three-id');

foreach ($array_1 as $key => $value) {
    $array_merged[$value] = $array_2[$key];
}

krsort($array_merged);

foreach ($array_merged as $key => $value) {
    $new_array_1[] = $key;
    $new_array_2[] = $value;
}

echo '<pre>'.print_r( $new_array_1, true ).print_r( $new_array_2, true ).'</pre>';
```